# Capacity Consumption Power BI

Tags: charts, powerbi, dax, powerquery, consumption

I'm trying to come up with a chart visualization like this in power BI:

X axis - time (month);
Y axis - % of consumption and remaining %;

[image: 100% for available capacity and them the consumption]

Would it be possible to do?

Also I'm in doubt how can I create a table to represent this goal, was thinking something like this:

```
        New column  New column  New column  New column  New column      New column
Date    Consumption Capacity    Remaining   % Com   %Rem    %Extra needed   %Com accum
01/07/2022   50     150         100         33%      67%    0%               33%
20/07/2022   20     150         80          13%      53%    0%               47%
30/07/2022   10     150         70           7%      47%    0%               53%
04/08/2022   40     150         30          27%      20%    0%               80%
05/08/2022   35     150         -5          23%      -3%    3%               103%
10/08/2022   10     150        -15           7%      -10%   10%              110%
```

Althought I am not seeing a way to calculate the last column %Com accum, being the accumulated of the sum of the new %Com with the previous from the actual row colum (since it's row calculation)

for the last row: 103% (previous %Com accum) + 7% (%Com) = 110%

also the available capacity is function of the time period we are in also, could be quarters or semesters, for example,
1Q 150, 2Q 200, 3Q, 150, 4Q, 200
1H 350, 2H 350

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using the Deneb custom visual. https://deneb-viz.github.io/